# Как лучше организовать видеопоток на C++ для просмотра в браузере?

Tags: c++, streaming, online-video

В общем, задача следующая:

Сотрудник работает в Windows-приложении (написано на C++), которое параллельно транслирует его веб-камеру, но не постоянно, а по запросу. Запрос трансляции может инициировать руководитель через интерфейс в браузере. Всё во внутренней интрасети предприятия.

На данный момент задача реализована так:

Приложение отправляет base64-jpeg кадры http post запросами на php сервер, сервер при получении создаёт файл с именем = ID сотрудника и записывает в него кадр. Так 20-25 раз в секунду. Руководитель видит список таких файлов в браузере, и по клику на конкретного сотрудника, с тем же интервалом начинает обращаться к серверу по имени файла и получать его контент, который загружается в img src="..." блока трансляции.

Система работает, но картинка дёргается, нет плавности. Кадры как-бы отскакивают назад временами. В общем чую, что реализация "топрная", но как правильно надо не знаю.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как вообще это правильно делается, потоковое видео?

Comment: Это какая-то система слежки за сотрудниками? :)

Answer (score 3):

Имитировать видео путём склеивания отдельных снапшотов не лучшая идея. К тому же сохранение каждого кадра в отдельный файл будет быстро захламлять диск.

В данном случае, я бы предложил следующее решение:

- На компе сотрудника крутится [RTSP](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTSP)-сервер, подключенный к Web-камере.
- Руководитесь подключается к серверу и смотрит видео, когда хочет.

Для минимизации потоков данных можно использовать multicast. Чтобы ограничить доступ, сервер можно дополнить системой аутентификации.

Для организации сервера и клиента можно использовать библиотеки live555, GStreamer, VLC... Можно как встроить функционал в код своего приложения, так и использовать готовые модули/плееры.

Если требуется сохранение видео-потока на диск, то это также может быть обеспечено с помощью упомянутых библиотек.

Тема, на самом деле, довольно обширная, но решать задачу имеет смысл всё же при помощи уже готовых компонентов.

Comment: Понятно... Вопрос: а как реализованы системы онлайн стримов (например игр), или тот же Скайп? (в плане постоянной передачи данных и плавного воспроизведения)